# The "surpassing" or "surpass" of X over Y?

Tags: grammar, word-choice, sentence-construction

I would like to know if I should use **surpassing** or **surpass** to refer to a situation when a quantitative indicator has surpassed another in a certain time period, such as in the following sentence:

> The **surpassing** / **surpass** of birth rate over mortality rate in the past
>   decade is a landmark in the demographic transition.

Answer (score 2):

First off, the verb to surpass (someone/something) doesn't need the preposition over, e.g. She surpassed her rivals. The book's success has surpassed everyone's expectations.

Besides, [the meaning](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/surpass) of this verb is *to do or be better than*, whereas what you mean seems to be "to be greater than a number or amount", and this is the meaning of the verb [to exceed](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/exceed), which doesn't need a preposition either. So, it would be correct to say that [the birth rate exceeds the mortality or death rate](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22birth%20rate%20exceeds%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en). With this in mind, you could rephrase your sentence for example, this way:

> The birth rate exceeding (the) death rate became a landmark in (the)
>   demographic transition in the past decade.

Answer (score 0):

It would be surpassing, and you would be able to tell 
if you were to rearrange your sentence. So, take the two things you are referring to, birth rate and mortality rate, and see which if surpassing or surpass fits more. The two sentences would then be "Birth rate surpassing mortality rate", or "Birth rate surpass mortality rate". Then, it would be clear that surpassing is the appropriate word.

Comment: “Surpassing” is the gerund - noun form of the verb- which is why this works (to some extent) and “surpass” doesn’t. “Birth rate surpasses mortality rate” is also grammatical.

Answer (score 0):

Your sentence is hard to read.  I would simplify the sentence and moving the  proposition in a more logical position

**From**

*The surpassing / surpass of birth rate over mortality rate in the past decade is a landmark in the demographic transition.*

**to**

*In the past decade, the birth rate surpassing morality rate became a landmark in demographic transition.*

---

Some Rules of thumb for good English:

1. Simplify the sentence structure
2. Try to use simpler words, not multi-syllable not so common words
3. Try to use one tense and try not to use "have" or "had"

Comment: It’s nice to give pointers, but please address the given question with a proper explanation. OP wants to know about the usage of surpass/surpassing.